# Search for a tag

Tags: search, vim, tags

I know approximately what the tag I'm looking for is. I know maybe a substring. Is there a fuzzyfinder-like plugin that lets me search through tags? For whatever reason, fuzzyfinder's tag mode hangs on me whenever I type `:FufTag<CR>`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No need for a plugin.  You can tell Vim to use a regular expression to find the relevant tag.

```
:tselect /pattern
```

See also [:help tag-regexp](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#tag-regexp).

Comment: I'd like to see a list of results too, instead of tabbing my way through all of them.

Comment: When the list reaches the bottom, it asks me to enter either a number or nothing to quit, how can I jump back to the top of the list?

Comment: @shengy: You can scroll around the list *until* you get to the prompt for the number.

Comment: @jamessan Yes, I know that, but the question I'm asking is how to return to the "scrolling" state when I accidentally scrolled to the prompt. I'm now using `:tselect` with no args to get back to the tag search.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [unite.vim](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim), it is like FuzzyFinder but can search for various of things like file, buffer, tags... You can also add your own things with plugins (see https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim/wiki/unite-plugins for full list). There is tags plugins which search the whole tag file so you can jump in functions in different files, or you can use [outline](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/h1mesuke/20101107/p1) plugin for quick navigation in one file.